# In QT Displaying real time data on tableview is not so much fast

Tags: qt

I am working in tool development project.where i am using QT standard framework to develop the UI part.
Right now i am stuck in displaying Real time data in Tableview. where i am using QStandarditem modal.
Real time data is coming very fast but displaying that data on UI is not that much fast.Is there any another way to improve the performance.

Comment: You should provide details about your design (preferably with short, concise and to the point code) so that someone can answer. Otherwise use profiler (Valgrind has Qt Creator integration) to see where the bottleneck lies - whether it is in Qt library or your code.

Comment: Note that QStandardItemModel is a very generic model, which can represent just about any data supported by Qt model-view system. As such, it has a lot of overhead, both memory and performance. Consider subclassing QAbstractTableModel instead, so you can use a data structure tailored for your use case.

Comment: Ok so You are saying that instead of using QStandardItem Model i have to use subclass of QAbstractTable model for  better performance.
I have one question regarding to QStandardItem Model
In my case i am updating the tableview for every single rows means
every time for every single rows QStandardItem Model internally send the data 
changed signal to tableview for UI Updation may be this is overhead so is there 
any way that QStandarditem model will notify to table view after some chunk of rows instead of every single rows.

Comment: @IshanShah You are merely speculating. Unless you measured it (e.g. with QElapsedTimer) or used a profiler you cannot say whether that is the bottleneck or something else is. You could very well implement your own model only to find out the performance is still as bad because the bottleneck was in fact elsewhere all along...

Comment: @Resurrection :Ok thanx....first i will measure the time of UI updation.

Comment: @hyde :Is there any way that QStandarditem model will notify to table view after some chunk of rows instead of every single row..

Comment: Resurrection is absolutely right about measuring first. Check out the docs, in particular http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#insertRows

Comment: Though subclassing your own model is one of important things to learn about Qt, and also one of the most complex parts of Qt. Even if you don't need to do it often, it will help you understand how the whole thing works (be sure to read the relevant docs and tutorials, you have to do everything right or things like updates just stop working).